# Javascript ajax request not running with Selenium tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, selenium

I'm trying to test the following use case with Selenium: 
- when user types something into a textarea, an ajax request is fired, text is added to the database (I'm using django and process request in a view.py), after a redirect the page displays entered text in a table row. 
- I use selenium LiveServerTest and sendKeys function to enter text into a textarea. However, it seems that Javascript is not triggered during the test at all. 
If I pause my test and enter text by hand, I again don't get my text displayed as I do when I run an actual server with django. 
Can anyone suggest what can cause this and/or the best way to test pages with Javascript using Selenium?

Comment: well it depends what version of selenium you are using.  If you are using WebDriver, then Selenium will execute actions just as a user would which would invoke javascript events natively.  If that's not happening, a couple things might be happening:  1) you are using a version of EdgeDriver/Geckodriver that doesn't have that capability yet. 2) the app is configured incorrectly somehow

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It looks like my main problem was that Selenium wouldn't run external Javascript files. I have pasted my script directly into html and it worked. Also had to add waits to let ajax requests complete.  In any case, now I need to figure out how to make Selenium run external scripts. Oh, and I'm using Selenium 3.0.1 with geckodriver 0.11.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not with Selenium, but with Django. I had to use StaticLiveServerTestCase instead of LiveServerTestCase for testing, otherwise the static files would not load. 
To test continuous Adjax request I had to add something like this:

wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, timeout=30)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "element_id")))

Comment: glad you figured it out!